# resignFirstResponder keyboard will NOT go away before segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am stumped and I hope someone can help.

I am calling the resign first responder method for all five of my text fields prior to a segue.  The segue occurs, if the keyboard was visible prior to the segue, the keyboard remains no matter what I do.  This did not happen in IOS6.  It is only happening in IOS7.

Thank you so much in advance for your assistance.

**Here is the scenario:**

The user touches one text field at time to enter data.  The keyboard has no problems changing from first responder from one field to the next and can be resigned from the DONE button without issues.  The problem comes when the user touches a field that will be populated from the picker view.  If the keyboard was visible from one of the previous text fields, it won't go away.

I have this code attempting to `resignFirstResponder` on the `editingDidBegin` action of two of the fields.  I am using these two fields to hold numbers but I am filling them from a picker on the next view.

```
- (IBAction)txtRatioOrHullTypeTouched:(id)sender 
{    
    // Hide the keyboard before the segue to the picker occurs.
    [self.txtPitch resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtRPM resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtSlipOrSpeed resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtRatio resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtHullType resignFirstResponder];

    segueToPicker = YES; // Raise flag indicating that this segue is to the picker.
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toPicker" sender:sender];
}
```

I also put this same code in the `viewWillDisappear` as shown here:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated // Unchanged
{
    // Hide the keyboard before the segue to the picker occurs.
    [self.txtPitch resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtRPM resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtSlipOrSpeed resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtRatio resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtHullType resignFirstResponder];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Both of these methods are on the initial view, ViewController.m file.

Comment: Try  [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up here removing the text field causing the problem and replacing them with buttons.  No scenario I tried (dozens) got this code to work as expected in IOS7, even though it all worked flawlessly in IOS6.

Comment: You're a hero @zaheer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the above and it worked as long as i dismissed the controller with a button. The function that was called when pressing the button could call the TextField's resignFirstResponder() function and all was well.

However, when an edge swipe was performed to dismiss the controller the keyboard kept popping up the next time I showed it. In my code I reuse the same controller between views. This might not be wise but, it's snappy!

After trying everything the internet had written (well not really, but pretty close) about this I found that i could implement the TextField's textViewShouldBeginEditing() and return false between the ViewControllers ViewDidDisappear and ViewDidAppear. It's ha hack, but it did the trick when nothing else worked.

I hope this helps you guys!

Swift code:

**In my ViewController**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  myTextField.allowEdit = true
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
  myTextField.allowEdit = false
}
```

**In my TextField class**

```
class MyTextField: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {
  var allowEdit = true

  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    return allowEdit
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `endEditing:` on the view controller with the text fields. Your `viewWillDisappear:` method will look like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried delaying the segue a few hundred milliseconds to give the keyboard a chance to animate out of the way?

Comment: Yes I have,  I tried one full second using the SLEEP command, the keyboard remains.

Comment: Ok, so here is what i have found with further investiagtion:  Using the **isFirstResponder** method I can see that the first responder does change from any of the 3 other text fields that opened it, to the one that calls the segue.

Comment: So it seems now that the text field that controls the keyboard will not allow resignation.  I used the **canResignFirstResponder** query on that field and the result (boolean) was FALSE.  I also noticed that i get a flashing cursor in the field even after the **resignFirstResponder** is called.

Answer (score 1):

I think due to the way you are leaving the view through a picker, without going through an exit, you need to include the following in your viewController:

```
- (BOOL) disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
      return NO;
}
```

---

Swift, 2017

```
override var disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal: Bool {
    get { return false }
    set { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Contributing my 2 cents worth. dismissing keyboard correctly on **iOS 9.2**, a minimalist sample, FYI.

```
...
@property (assign) BOOL isTransitioning;
...

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    self.isTransitioning = YES;
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated {
    self.isTransitioning = YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    self.isTransitioning = NO;
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL) animated {
    self.isTransitioning = NO;
}

-(BOOL) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView*) tv {
  if (self.isTransitioning) {
   return NO;
  } 
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So it seems now that the text field that controls the keyboard will not allow resignation. I used the canResignFirstResponder query on that field and the result (boolean) was FALSE. I also noticed that i get a flashing cursor in the field even after the resignFirstResponder is called. –  Larry J Oct 25 '13 at 23:32

I know this is old, but I had a similar issue and wanted to share what worked for me in case it might help anyone else:

After reading the above comment I found that moving `[self.view endEditing:YES]` from where I had it in **textFieldDidBeginEditing** to **textFieldSHOULDBeginEditing** did the trick for me. Now the keyboard is dismissing properly before my segue.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Zaheer's comment into Swift this works very well for me.

```
 view.endEditing(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem i have frequently.  My best method to cope is creating a clear button under the keyboard and having that call a dismiss helper.  Control the clear button by toggling its isHidden property.  Tapping outside the keyboard will hit that clear button and call the dismiss helper.  What it won't do is trigger your segue, the user will need to tap again to navigate out but that keyboard will be gone.

in viewDidLoad():

```
    var clearButton: UIButton!
    self.clearButton = UIButton(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.clearButton.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dismissHelper(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(self.clearButton)
    self.clearButton.isHidden = true
```

Then add the dismiss helper:

```
func dismissHelper(_ sender: UIButton?) {
    self.clearButton.isHidden = true
    view.endEditing(true)
}


func displayClearButton(){
    print("display clear button, hidden = false")
    self.clearButton.isHidden = false
}
```

then on your textfield add the target

```
self.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.displayClearButton), for: .editingDidBegin)
```